# Highcharts wrap extend not working from 11.3.0 onwards

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Changing the svg desc tag content using highcharts wrap extend.

```
Highgarts.wrap(Highcharts.SVGRenderer.proptype, "init", function(proceed) {proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);this.box.children[0].innerHTML= "my content";})
```

Which is working in 11.2.0 version but it is not working in latest version. Please help me out resolving this.

Comment: Hi @anil kumar Reddy, Since Highcharts v.11.3 `SVGRenderer` is initialized without calling the `init` method. The best solution is to change the `desc` content in another place, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5azcopxv/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Yes it works but I wonder why removed this thing  from init

Comment: This is the inner part of Highcharts so such things may change from version to version.